# Cant run the built after installing the package react-native-jsi-image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When I install the package npm I react-native-jsi-image on android and then npx react-native run-android it fails my built and gives me this error can anyone please help me to fix this problem i am using react native cli with very latest version of react native https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-jsi-image

The Error:

```
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
132 actionable tasks: 115 executed, 17 up-to-date
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-

* What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-jsi-image:configureCMakeDebug\[arm64-v8a\]'.

> \[CXX1405\] error when building with cmake using C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\notification_redirection-main\\notification_redirection-main\\node_modules\\react-native-jsi-image\\android\\CMakeLists.txt: -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
> \-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
> \-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Andriod Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe - skipped
> \-- Detecting C compile features
> \-- Detecting C compile features - done
> \-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
> \-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
> \-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Andriod Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe - skipped
> \-- Detecting CXX compile features
> \-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
> \-- Configuring done

C++ build system \[configure\] failed while executing:
@echo off
"D:\\Andriod Sdk\\cmake\\3.18.1\\bin\\cmake.exe" ^
"-HC:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\notification_redirection-main\\notification_redirection-main\\node_modules\\react-native-jsi-image\\android"
^
"-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android" ^
"-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON" ^
"-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=16" ^
"-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-16" ^
"-DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a" ^
"-DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a" ^
"-DANDROID_NDK=D:\\Andriod Sdk\\ndk\\23.1.7779620" ^
"-DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=D:\\Andriod Sdk\\ndk\\23.1.7779620" ^
"-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\\Andriod Sdk\\ndk\\23.1.7779620\\build\\cmake\\android.toolchain.cmake" ^
"-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=D:\\Andriod Sdk\\cmake\\3.18.1\\bin\\ninja.exe" ^
"-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-O2 -frtti -fexceptions -Wall -fstack-protector-all" ^
"-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\notification_redirection-main\\notification_redirection-main\\node_modules\\react-native-jsi-image\\android\\build\\intermediates\\cxx\\Debug\\3ti2o4y3\\obj\\arm64-v8a" ^
"-DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\notification_redirection-main\\notification_redirection-main\\node_modules\\react-native-jsi-image\\android\\build\\intermediates\\cxx\\Debug\\3ti2o4y3\\obj\\arm64-v8a" ^
"-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" ^
"-BC:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\notification_redirection-main\\notification_redirection-main\\node_modules\\react-native-jsi-image\\android\\.cxx\\Debug\\3ti2o4y3\\arm64-v8a" ^
\-GNinja
from C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\notification_redirection-main\\notification_redirection-main\\node_modules\\react-native-jsi-image\\android
CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
No project() command is present.  The top-level CMakeLists.txt file must
contain a literal, direct call to the project() command.  Add a line of
code such as

      project(ProjectName)
    
    near the top of the file, but after cmake_minimum_required().
    
    CMake is pretending there is a "project(Project)" command on the first
    line.

This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning at D:/Andriod Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android-legacy.toolchain.cmake:416 (message):
An old version of CMake is being used that cannot automatically detect
compiler attributes.  Compiler identification is being bypassed.  Some
values may be wrong or missing.  Update to CMake 3.19 or newer to use
CMake's built-in compiler identification.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
D:/Andriod Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:55 (include)
D:/Andriod Sdk/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:93 (include)

CMake Warning at D:/Andriod Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android-legacy.toolchain.cmake:416 (message):
An old version of CMake is being used that cannot automatically detect
compiler attributes.  Compiler identification is being bypassed.  Some
values may be wrong or missing.  Update to CMake 3.19 or newer to use
CMake's built-in compiler identification.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
D:/Andriod Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:55 (include)
C:/Users/me/Downloads/notification_redirection-main/notification_redirection-main/node_modules/react-native-jsi-image/android/.cxx/Debug/3ti2o4y3/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/3.18.1-g262b901-dirty/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
C:/Users/me/Downloads/notification_redirection-main/notification_redirection-main/node_modules/react-native-jsi-image/android/.cxx/Debug/3ti2o4y3/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)

CMake Warning at D:/Andriod Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android-legacy.toolchain.cmake:416 (message):
An old version of CMake is being used that cannot automatically detect
compiler attributes.  Compiler identification is being bypassed.  Some
values may be wrong or missing.  Update to CMake 3.19 or newer to use
CMake's built-in compiler identification.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
D:/Andriod Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:55 (include)
C:/Users/me/Downloads/notification_redirection-main/notification_redirection-main/node_modules/react-native-jsi-image/android/.cxx/Debug/3ti2o4y3/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/3.18.1-g262b901-dirty/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
C:/Users/me/Downloads/notification_redirection-main/notification_redirection-main/node_modules/react-native-jsi-image/android/.cxx/Debug/3ti2o4y3/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (add_library):
Cannot find source file:

      ../cpp/TypedArray/TypedArray.cpp
    
    Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
    .hpp .hxx .in .txx

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (add_library):
No SOURCES given to target: jsi-image

CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.

* Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-

* What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 10s

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-

* What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-jsi-image:configureCMakeDebug\[arm64-v8a\]'.

> \[CXX1405\] error when building with cmake using C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\notification_redirection-main\\notification_redirection-main\\node_modules\\react-native-jsi-image\\android\\CMakeLists.txt: -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
> \-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
> \-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Andriod Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe - skipped
> \-- Detecting C compile features
> \-- Detecting C compile features - done
> \-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
> \-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
> \-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Andriod Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe - skipped
> \-- Detecting CXX compile features
> \-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
> \-- Configuring done

C++ build system \[configure\] failed while executing:
@echo off
"D:\\Andriod Sdk\\cmake\\3.18.1\\bin\\cmake.exe" ^
"-HC:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\notification_redirection-main\\notification_redirection-main\\node_modules\\react-native-jsi-image\\android"
^
"-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android" ^
"-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON" ^
"-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=16" ^
"-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-16" ^
"-DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a" ^
"-DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a" ^
"-DANDROID_NDK=D:\\Andriod Sdk\\ndk\\23.1.7779620" ^
"-DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=D:\\Andriod Sdk\\ndk\\23.1.7779620" ^
"-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\\Andriod Sdk\\ndk\\23.1.7779620\\build\\cmake\\android.toolchain.cmake" ^
"-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=D:\\Andriod Sdk\\cmake\\3.18.1\\bin\\ninja.exe" ^
"-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-O2 -frtti -fexceptions -Wall -fstack-protector-all" ^
"-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\notification_redirection-main\\notification_redirection-main\\node_modules\\react-native-jsi-image\\android\\build\\intermediates\\cxx\\Debug\\3ti2o4y3\\obj\\arm64-v8a" ^
"-DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\notification_redirection-main\\notification_redirection-main\\node_modules\\react-native-jsi-image\\android\\build\\intermediates\\cxx\\Debug\\3ti2o4y3\\obj\\arm64-v8a" ^
"-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" ^
"-BC:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\notification_redirection-main\\notification_redirection-main\\node_modules\\react-native-jsi-image\\android\\.cxx\\Debug\\3ti2o4y3\\arm64-v8a" ^
\-GNinja
from C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\notification_redirection-main\\notification_redirection-main\\node_modules\\react-native-jsi-image\\android
CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
No project() command is present.  The top-level CMakeLists.txt file must
contain a literal, direct call to the project() command.  Add a line of
code such as

      project(ProjectName)
    
    near the top of the file, but after cmake_minimum_required().
    
    CMake is pretending there is a "project(Project)" command on the first
    line.

This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning at D:/Andriod Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android-legacy.toolchain.cmake:416 (message):
An old version of CMake is being used that cannot automatically detect
compiler attributes.  Compiler identification is being bypassed.  Some
values may be wrong or missing.  Update to CMake 3.19 or newer to use
CMake's built-in compiler identification.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
D:/Andriod Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:55 (include)
D:/Andriod Sdk/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:93 (include)

CMake Warning at D:/Andriod Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android-legacy.toolchain.cmake:416 (message):
An old version of CMake is being used that cannot automatically detect
compiler attributes.  Compiler identification is being bypassed.  Some
values may be wrong or missing.  Update to CMake 3.19 or newer to use
CMake's built-in compiler identification.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
D:/Andriod Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:55 (include)
C:/Users/me/Downloads/notification_redirection-main/notification_redirection-main/node_modules/react-native-jsi-image/android/.cxx/Debug/3ti2o4y3/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/3.18.1-g262b901-dirty/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
C:/Users/me/Downloads/notification_redirection-main/notification_redirection-main/node_modules/react-native-jsi-image/android/.cxx/Debug/3ti2o4y3/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)

CMake Warning at D:/Andriod Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android-legacy.toolchain.cmake:416 (message):
An old version of CMake is being used that cannot automatically detect
compiler attributes.  Compiler identification is being bypassed.  Some
values may be wrong or missing.  Update to CMake 3.19 or newer to use
CMake's built-in compiler identification.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
D:/Andriod Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:55 (include)
C:/Users/me/Downloads/notification_redirection-main/notification_redirection-main/node_modules/react-native-jsi-image/android/.cxx/Debug/3ti2o4y3/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/3.18.1-g262b901-dirty/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
C:/Users/me/Downloads/notification_redirection-main/notification_redirection-main/node_modules/react-native-jsi-image/android/.cxx/Debug/3ti2o4y3/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (add_library):
Cannot find source file:

      ../cpp/TypedArray/TypedArray.cpp
    
    Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
    .hpp .hxx .in .txx

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (add_library):
No SOURCES given to target: jsi-image

CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.

* Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-

* What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 10s

    at makeError (C:\Users\me\Downloads\notification_redirection-main\notification_redirection-main\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\me\Downloads\notification_redirection-main\notification_redirection-main\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\me\Downloads\notification_redirection-main\notification_redirection-main\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\me\Downloads\notification_redirection-main\notification_redirection-main\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
\`\`
```

Answer (score -1):

Update your CMake version to the latest available. Then try.

Comment: So if i push my code to production using this package will it work?

Comment: Yes if your code get compiled successfully  using latest CMake version then it will surely work.